# Parsing an URL in SVNKit

Tags: java, svn, url, svnkit

I'm trying to parse an URL in order to obtain the current branch or trunk.

```
public SVNConnector(String s_Url, String login, String password, String project) {
        try {
            url = SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(s_Url);
            ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = new BasicAuthenticationManager(login, password);
            DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
            repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(url, null);
            repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
            this.projectName = project;
            latestRevision = repository.getLatestRevision();
        } catch (SVNException svne) {
            logger.error("Impossible to connect to SVN repository. s_Url: "+s_Url+" login:"+login+" password: "+password, svne);
        }
    }
```

My URL is something like `http://10.61.128.222/svn/i18ntest/trunk` or `http://10.61.128.222/svn/PFT/branches/protoi18n` and I need a method where I could enter this URL and it would return `/trunk/` or `/branches/protoi18n/`, so I could run this:

```
public List<OutputElement> retrieveI18nFiles() throws SVNException {
        List<OutputElement> outs = new ArrayList<OutputElement>();
        String path = url.getPath()+"/core/src/main/resources/fr/gefco/"+projectName+"/i18n/"; // this is not working!

        latestRevision = repository.getLatestRevision();

        // For some reason, type safety is not insured in SVNKit, even if generics are around for some years, now
        Collection<SVNDirEntry> entries = repository.getDir(path, latestRevision, (SVNProperties)null, (Collection<SVNDirEntry>)null);
        for (SVNDirEntry entry : entries) {
            OutputElement out = new OutputElement();
            out.setEntry(entry);
            out.setOut(retrieveOutputStream(entry,path));
            outs.add(out);
        }
        return outs;

    }
```

`url.getPath()` is returning `/svn/i18ntest/trunk/`, which is not what I need. Of course, I could parse it to get the bit I need, but I would like to know first if SVNKit provides any already proven way to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with `SVNRepository` you need paths relative to the repository root. You may retrieve the repository root URL using `SVNURL root = repository.getRepositoryRoot(true)` and then use `SVNURLUtil.getRelativeURL(root, url, false)` to get the relative path between your `url` and the repository root URL.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. Too bad SVNURLUtil is in an "internal" package and not documented...